# How to access Outlook Archive (.pst) emails

Tags: .net, outlook

I have a .PST file for archive folder.

What I need to is to access the .PST file 
and retrieve all emails under certain folder and then save them as .MSG files on a local machine.

How can I access the .PST **`Archive`** folder using .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a 3rd party library from [ASPOSE](http://www.aspose.com/) to read .PST files.

Answer (score 1):

Check out PST .NET

http://www.independentsoft.de/pst/index.html

might be able to help you. It costs, but they will send you a free evaluation version.

Answer (score 1):

The official [Microsoft PST SDK](http://pstsdk.codeplex.com/), supported and for free from Microsoft.

it looks like it's available for C++ but it should be possible to use it from .NET with DLLImport.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail And Outlook is one of the most important tools in their daily lives. The problem is that most get so many emails that it is hard to keep your inbox organized and not full of random, unnecessary emails. Gmail offers users multiple ways to organize and sort their emails into different folders, tabs, and tags but in a time where Googles search can scan millions of words per second why is it necessary to put so much effort into keeping your Gmail organized?

Luckily, Gmail has an archiving tool that will help you clean up the interface without causing you to spend several days placing each email into a distinct folder.

What is archiving ?
The act of archiving emails in Gmail is taking it and placing it in a folder where it will continue to exist but will no longer be cluttering your inbox. The best part about this is that it will still be accessible in the future if needed. Gmail handles this task fantastically as it allows users to quickly and [best way to archive outlook emails](http://www.techtrick.in/description/4705-best-way-to-archive-outlook-and-gmail-emails) .

How to Create a PST File for Outlook 2016

- Open Outlook 2016 and Click the Home tab > New Items > More Items >
  Outlook Data File.
- Give your PST Outlook data file a name and click OK.
- With the outlook pst file created, Outlook automatically adds it to
  your Profile on the left side of the Home Tab. Personally, We like to
  add the Inbox and Sent Items folders so we can begin archiving old
  email from my online Mailbox into my PST archive. To do this (or
  create any folder for that matter), just Right Click the new PST
  folder and Click New Folder.
- Once you create the folders you need, just drag-and-drop emails into
  your PST file and they will move to your new archive wherever you
  created it.